# Py Elisticsearch query slow on laptop

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am running a simple python elasticsearch query in my script which evaluates instantly on my workstation, but has a ~3 second lag on my laptop. I'm thinking it is a memory usage thing but I'm not sure the best way to adjust that.

```
def searchData(query):
     sdat = es.search(index="roasts", doc_type="roast", q=query)
```

The indexed JSON files are very small. Was thinking this would be instant. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're going to need some more information. What is your query? Is your workstation on a local network whereas your laptop isn't? What are your ES client settings?